# jQuery dynamic fields after validation are disappearing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a problem with my `jQuery` and with validation.

Here is my Code:

```js
var fielddd = 1;
$(document).on('click', '.btn.add-field', function() {
  fielddd++;
  $('#newfield').append('<textarea class="from-control" name="somename[]" id="field_' + field + '"></textarea>' + '<button class="btn add-field">add</button>' + '<textarea class="from-control" name="somename2[]" id="field_' + field + '"></textarea>');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <textarea class="from-control"  name="somename[]" id="field"></textarea>
  <button class="btn add-field">add</button>
  <textarea class="from-control" name="somename2[]" id="field"></textarea>
</div>
<div class="row" id="newfield">
  <!-- new textarea -->
</div>
```

The problem is that I have an validation and I have an button submit, after checking that one field empty is, the code make and redirect and after this redirect to the same page so that user can give his parameter in `textarea`. But after this redirect, by the user  added field are **`disappeared`**.

How can I fix it?

Comment: You can use the localstorage to store the added fields and readd them onload

Comment: Why are you reloading the page? If you use AJAX you do not need to reload

Comment: @mplungjan i am using an framework an the framework make it to validate the input data

Comment: So why not tell use the complete story?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone what do you mean?

Comment: @mplungjan because there are an big code and is hard then to explain

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i have an name as array and by using post method

Comment: @LawrenceCherone look there i add name

Comment: @Christian then use that to build the dom, it sounds like your backend code is badly designed you should be checking all fields not one and then doing a redirect. This is common with javascript, as it does not hold state.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone i am using MVC and the data is sending to controller and there is the validation and if the validation are not passed then it make an redirect. So my question was if i can fix it  in jQuery so that after redirect i have the same field there?

Comment: MVC or not you shouldn't be redirecting...

Comment: it redirect to the same page and i have an function there so i can put the old data. But as i said i need the same fields with the same id and name that have **somename1,2,3,4...**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same id in each and every textarea. Id must be unique. Mistakenly you are using "field" which must be replaced with "fielddd" that is being incremented.

```js
var fielddd = 1;
$(document).on('click', '.btn.add-field', function() {
  fielddd++;
  $('#newfield').append('<textarea class="from-control" id="field_' + fielddd + '"></textarea>' + '<button class="btn add-field">add</button>' + '<textarea class="from-control" id="field_' + fielddd + '"></textarea>');
});
```

Comment: i am usind name for that with an array somename[] so that for each added field i have an somename1,2,3,4....

Comment: name can be redundant but id field must not have redundancy

Comment: fo that what i am doing i need name